# Pegar informações de um "Object"

Tags: javascript

Estou usando uma API para pegar alguns dados de filmes, porém eu queria pegar somente as informações "name" dos gêneros, que são "Ação, Aventura, Comédia, Fantasia".
Porém o numero de gêneros nem sempre é o mesmo, as vezes são 2, 3..

```
genres: [
    {id: 28, name: "Ação"},
    {id: 12, name: "Aventura"},
    {id: 35, name: "Comédia"},
    {id: 14, name: "Fantasia"}
]
```

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/166426?api_key=MINHA-API&language=pt-BR').then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.genres);
```

Ao usar desse modo, o console retorna 4 Object e dentro deles informações id e name

```
(4) [Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Se eu usar

```
console.log(response.genres[3].name);
```

Ele me retorna o gênero do objeto 3, que é "Fantasia", mas se eu procurar um filme que possua 2 gêneros por exemplo, ele já da erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta utilizar o método `map` do *array* e retornar apenas o atributo `name`:

```
let names = genres.map(genre => genre.name);
```

Veja o exemplo:

```js
const genres = [
    {id: 28, name: "Ação"},
    {id: 12, name: "Aventura"},
    {id: 35, name: "Comédia"},
    {id: 14, name: "Fantasia"}
];

let names = genres.map(genre => genre.name);

console.log(names);
```

Comment: Bom, com esse código ele sempre me retorna esses 4 gêneros.
Tbm há outros gêneros que podem ocorrer, não só esses 4

Comment: Sim, porque eu coloquei apenas 4 no exemplo. Você precisa adaptar para o seu problema, colocando `response.genres.map(genre => genre.name)`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @YuriFrança você pode marcar a resposta como aceita utilizando o botão **✓** logo abaixo da pontuação da resposta, no lado esquerdo da mesma.